# ASP.net Server Side Code

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a quick question. Basically since jQuery/Javascript is so popular now for performing tasks client-side is there now much of a need to process things server side with server side code?

I mean, we have web services which can respond to ajax requests and I cannot think of a good reason why you would want to perform any related tasks in ASP.net for example.

Unless i'm missing the point but I would like someone else's opinion.

I suppose from one perspective, you only need to process things with jQuery/ajax for example when you need to and the rest should be done server-side, but with things like jQuery its so quick to actually do it all client side.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is probably going to get closed because it's almost entirely opinion based. Personally, I prefer to do almost everything server-side where possible because dynamically typed client-side languages do my head in. And I'm more used to server-side code. Long and short of it: it depends, and is entirely based on the requirements of the system. =]

Comment: Where is ur question?

Comment: Thats great thanks Sean. Yes I agree it is opinion based and I just wanted someone else to confirm that. I just wanted to make sure there was no other reason I had missed :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From design patterns perspective it's not good to mix views with business logic. So my answer to your question is: "It depends ...". If services have all logic and return response which is only use to bind & display - it is ok in my opinion. But it's not ok to mix views and some business logic.

Please also remember that of course services which about you're writing are server side. Probably it's clear for you, but I would like to underline this fact that not only Web Forms/MVC projects are server side, but of course all web services too.

Comment: Thank you, yes absolutely. Web Services are server-side. I was referring to actual code-behind which would require postback to be executed. I understand the mixing of views, so yes it should not be mixed with business logic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're question is opinion based, which might get down votes. So quickly try to go to this site: http://programmers.stackexchange.com that is the place to ask for questions like these.

Secondly, AJAX was meant to be a script that runs behind the scenes. If you would use ASP.NET to submit the forms, then there is actually nothing that we could call `Ajax`. ASP.NET and jQuery are totally different stuff; which I am afraid you have already mentioned! So what you're trying to do?

When you're performing Ajax, you are actually mixing the Client-side (jQuery) with Server-Side (In your case, ASP.NET). In other words, ajax would require them both. Because this is what ajax does:

1. Makes a request to server on the back end. `-->` Client Side starts.
2. Server reads it. `-->` Server Side starts.
3. Server provides the response. `-->` Server side ends.
4. Browser write the data with the help of jQuery. `-->` Client Side ends.

**Since you're using ASP.NET:**

I will assume that you're well known to the Variables, then you can do this trick too.

```
var stuff ="";
if(IsPost) {
  // run the code to save the data..which ajax would have..
  stuff="Hey change in lines buddy!";
}
```

Now in the body tag, you can write this:

```
<div>@stuff</div>
```

What it would do? It will on the first page load won't do anything. But once the form is submitted `stuff` will get a value, and will be written in the page. That can be next to ajax, but not ajax! Client side would perform stuff without POSTBACK, but ASP.NET form submit would require the form to first reach the server. This code would do exactly what ajax would do, send the data then recieve response, then write the result in the page.

There's still a difference, but both are good. Do what would please you, not what others like!

Good luck, Cheers!